FlatList Not Clickable in React Native App on iOS 17++
I'm encountering an issue with my mobile application built with React Native, using React version 16.13.1 and Node 15.3. The FlatList on one page of my app isn't clickable when deployed to production on iOS 17++ devices, but it works fine in the simulator and on devices during development.
Strangely, the FlatList works on other pages within the same app. I've compared the working and non-working pages and can't find any significant differences in their code.
This issue only occurs on iOS 17++.
No errors appear in the logs when the issue occurs.
Here is the code for the problematic page and the working page:
**Code for the Problematic Page:
**
export interface PickupDropoffListProps {
    navigation: CompositeNavigationProp<
        BottomTabNavigationProp<BottomTabParamList, 'Pickup' | 'Dropoff'>,
        StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
    >;
    route: RouteProp<BottomTabParamList, 'Pickup' | 'Dropoff'>;
    pickup?: boolean;
}

const PickupDropoffList = (props: PickupDropoffListProps) => {
    const { pickup } = props.route.params;
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    const { account, pickupdropoff } = useContext(RootStoreContext);
    useNotification({ onSendDeviceToken: account.sendDeviceToken, activate: pickup });
    const { pickups, dropoffs, loading, error } = pickupdropoff;
    const data = useMemo(() => (pickup ? pickups : dropoffs), [pickups, dropoffs]);

    useEffect(() => {
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
            if (pickup) {
                pickupdropoff.getPickups();
                account.getProfile();

                return;
            }

            pickupdropoff.getDropoffs();
        });
    }, []);

    const onGetData = useCallback(() => {
        // get for pickup screen
        if (pickup) {
            return flowResult(pickupdropoff.getPickups());
        }

        // get for dropoff screen
        return flowResult(pickupdropoff.getDropoffs());
    }, []);

    const onRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            setRefresh(true);
            onGetData();
        } catch (err: any) {
            Alert.alert('Warning', err.message || 'Something went wrong!');
        } finally {
            setRefresh(false);
        }
    }, []);

    const onClickItem = useCallback((id: number) => {
        props.navigation.push('PickupDropoffDetail', { id, pickup });
    }, []);

    const onRenderItem: ListRenderItem<DeliveryAdapter> = useCallback(
        ({ item }) => (
            <Item title={item.name} total={item.deliveries.length} onPress={() => onClickItem(item.id)} />
        ),
        [],
    );

    const onListEmptyComponent = useCallback(
        () => (
            <StateList
                error={error}
                loading={loading}
                empty={data.length <= 0}
                onRefresh={() => onGetData()}
            />
        ),
        [error, loading, data],
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar />
            <Header
                title={pickup ? 'Pick Up Jobs' : 'Drop Off Jobs'}
                background={pickup ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}
            />
            <Animatable.View
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                animation="fadeInUp"
                delay={200}
                duration={200}
                useNativeDriver
            >
                <FlatList
                    refreshControl={<RefreshControl onRefresh={onRefresh} refreshing={refresh} />}
                    data={data}
                    initialNumToRender={10}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Space height={20} />}
                    ListHeaderComponent={() => <Space height={20} />}
                    ListFooterComponent={() => <Space height={20} />}
                    ListEmptyComponent={onListEmptyComponent}
                    renderItem={onRenderItem}
                />
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Color.BACKGROUND,
    },
});

export default observer(PickupDropoffList);

enter image description here
**Code for the Working Page:
**
export interface PickupDropoffListProps {
    navigation: CompositeNavigationProp<
        BottomTabNavigationProp<BottomTabParamList, 'Pickup' | 'Dropoff'>,
        StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
    >;
    route: RouteProp<BottomTabParamList, 'Pickup' | 'Dropoff'>;
    pickup?: boolean;
}

const PickupDropoffList = (props: PickupDropoffListProps) => {
    const { pickup } = props.route.params;
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    const { account, pickupdropoff } = useContext(RootStoreContext);
    useNotification({ onSendDeviceToken: account.sendDeviceToken, activate: pickup });
    const { pickups, dropoffs, loading, error } = pickupdropoff;
    const data = useMemo(() => (pickup ? pickups : dropoffs), [pickups, dropoffs]);

    useEffect(() => {
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
            if (pickup) {
                pickupdropoff.getPickups();
                account.getProfile();

                return;
            }

            pickupdropoff.getDropoffs();
        });
    }, []);

    const onGetData = useCallback(() => {
        // get for pickup screen
        if (pickup) {
            return flowResult(pickupdropoff.getPickups());
        }

        // get for dropoff screen
        return flowResult(pickupdropoff.getDropoffs());
    }, []);

    const onRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            setRefresh(true);
            onGetData();
        } catch (err: any) {
            Alert.alert('Warning', err.message || 'Something went wrong!');
        } finally {
            setRefresh(false);
        }
    }, []);

    const onClickItem = useCallback((id: number) => {
        props.navigation.push('PickupDropoffDetail', { id, pickup });
    }, []);

    const onRenderItem: ListRenderItem<DeliveryAdapter> = useCallback(
        ({ item }) => (
            <Item title={item.name} total={item.deliveries.length} onPress={() => onClickItem(item.id)} />
        ),
        [],
    );

    const onListEmptyComponent = useCallback(
        () => (
            <StateList
                error={error}
                loading={loading}
                empty={data.length <= 0}
                onRefresh={() => onGetData()}
            />
        ),
        [error, loading, data],
    );

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar />
            <Header
                title={pickup ? 'Pick Up Jobs' : 'Drop Off Jobs'}
                background={pickup ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}
            />
            <Animatable.View
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                animation="fadeInUp"
                delay={200}
                duration={200}
                useNativeDriver
            >
                <FlatList
                    refreshControl={<RefreshControl onRefresh={onRefresh} refreshing={refresh} />}
                    data={data}
                    initialNumToRender={10}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Space height={20} />}
                    ListHeaderComponent={() => <Space height={20} />}
                    ListFooterComponent={() => <Space height={20} />}
                    ListEmptyComponent={onListEmptyComponent}
                    renderItem={onRenderItem}
                />
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Color.BACKGROUND,
    },
});

export default observer(PickupDropoffList);

enter image description here
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any ideas on what might be causing this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
